# Infinite stream of data via AJAX to update fields in webpage?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

Note: This is my first question on here.

**Short version of the question:**

If I'm running a server-side script that can output data (real-time sensor readings with values that change very rapidly), is it more appropriate to use AJAX to repeatedly request the most recent script output, or is it more appropriate to have the script output the data in an endless stream and use AJAX to read, parse, and output that data as it streams over? Is the second option even possible, or does AJAX anticipate some kind of end-of-file flag before processing anything?

**Very long version of the question:**

I am building an in-car computer comprised of an Arduino (to read sensors) and a Raspberry Pi and a 10" LCD. I'm streaming the data from the Arduino to the Raspberry Pi via serial communication, in the following format:

```
output-timestamp: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, etc.
```

With Chrome/Chromium extensions, I can read serial data directly into the browser, which allows me to display the sensor value in real time. And with HTML5, I can display that serial data visually with rotating image layers, simulating the various gauges in a typical car instrument cluster.

HOWEVER. Running raspian on the Raspberry Pi, the version of Chromium available doesn't have HTML5 support. I could either re-write my animations, or I can create a cross-browser solution. I've decided to go with the latter, even though I'm the only one who is going to use this thing.

On the Raspberry, I've written a perl script that grabs the serial data and outputs it when ran. I can tweak the code to either write a single line of data:

```
output-timestamp: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, etc.
```

Or I can write it to endlessly stream:

```
output-timestamp: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, etc.
output-timestamp: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, etc.
output-timestamp: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, etc.
etc., etc.
```

If I'm going to run an AJAX call to grab the data, is it more appropriate to have the perl script output the data once, and then have AJAX request the most recent version of the script again and again, very rapidly, or should I have the perl script endlessly stream the sensor data and use AJAX to read, parse, and display the data as it streams? And is the second option even possible, or does AJAX waiting for some kind of end-of-file flag before it begins processing?

In either way of doing it, the updates need to happen very rapidly; I'm pulling RPMs, accelerometer signals, speedometer signals, etc., so we're looking at very rapid updates to the display.

Answer (score 1):

There are various frameworks that will help you communicate in real time over a http/json interface.

[Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/) has excellent Websockets support, and is able to stream data in much the way you want.

In older browsers add one of the shims from [Modernizer](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-sockets) which will gracefully downgrade websockets to a polling mechanism as needed.

Here's an example echo server using Mojolicious::Lite, part of the same package on Mojolicious but with a simpler api.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => 'index';

websocket '/echo' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->on(message => sub {
            my ($self, $msg) = @_;
            my ($s,$m,$h) = localtime(time);
            $self->send({ json => { text => $msg, time=> "$h:$m:$s" }});
        });
};

app->start;

__DATA__
@@ index.html.ep
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(function () {
          var log = function (text) { $('#log').val( $('#log').val() + text + "\n"); };

          var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/echo');
          ws.onopen = function () { log('Connection opened'); };

          ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
            var res = JSON.parse(msg.data);
            log(res.time + '> '  + res.text); 
          };

         $('#msg').keydown(function (e) {
             if (e.keyCode == 13 && $('#msg').val()) {
                 ws.send($('#msg').val());
                 $('#msg').val('');
             }
           });
         });
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="msg" placeholder="Type Your Message Here" /><br>
    <textarea id="log" readonly></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

You can start this program using `perl app.pl daemon`, as well as host it on the various http servers such as apache.

When you start this you should see;

[image: Output from script]

Notice how the timestamp is added server side and the complete message sent back.

Comment: Thank you so much, harvey.

As I'm going through the code and modifying it, I'm trying to understand exactly how this works.

Since I'm trying to get a stream of data to flow in some manner, it appears as though the only way this works is if the javascript portion of the code makes multiple calls to the server.

This portion here, for example:

**ws.send($('#msg').val());**

Comment: You can extend this example very easily, add a global variable `my @connections = ();`. Create a new websocket end point such eg `websocket '/stream => sub { my $self = shift; push @connections, $self }'`. Now you can stream to the clients without having to be polled using as an example `foreach my $c (@connections) { $c->send({text=>'Hello';}) sleep 2; };`. In this way you can send a constant stream of data to all clients, don't forget to remove connects when clients disconnect. See (this)[https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Writing-websocket-chat-using-Mojolicious-Lite] for more details.